# Google sheets request through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets

This is my first question here, I have been looking around but I couldn't find an answer.

Actually, I had done a code that reads through getJSON a google sheets document, it takes values, save to an Array and return it to use in an HTML document (there are a series of URLs)

```
var contentendorArray = new Array();
 for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
   //there are 5 tables that I want to access

   // Make sure it is public or set to Anyone with link can view
   var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/URL/" + i + "/public/values?alt=json";
   console.log(url);

   //accessing the Json
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     var entry = data.feed.entry[0];

     $(entry).each(function() {
       //Get the value from the table
       var allInfo = this.gsx$allinfo.$t;

       //Save it to an array
       contentendorArray[i];

       //I orderered
       contentendorArray = contentendorArray.sort();
    });
  });
}

//After all this I will use it to create a menu`
```

The thing is that the values are not saved on the Global Array correctly and the I can't access later to use it.

**26/06/2017 EDIT**
I tried this

```
var contentendorArray = new Array();

var contentendorArrayWithValue = contentendorArray.sort();

 for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {


 // Make sure it is public or set to Anyone with link can view
 var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1_J6GQRApOyza_dSO2Rf10YNNT_j_f9ZbS0rhzwZgiDk/" + i + "/public/values?alt=json";
console.log(url);

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

  var entry = data.feed.entry[0];

$(entry).each(function(){
    var allInfo = this.gsx$allinfo.$t;
    contentendorArray[i];
  }); 
 });
}
```

But the Chrome console is telling me that's 'undefined' when I try to `console.log` the array. I'm apologize but I'm a newie.

Kind regards

Comment: try to create new array before forloop and assign this `contentendorArray.sort();` in new created array

Comment: you can't use `i`ndexes inside async executed callbacks

Comment: Then how I can make it sync the callback, I'm so sorry but I'm totally stucked

Comment: what does `data` contain when you receive the response? If `entry` is undefined it's either because `data` does not contain anything, or because it does not have the structure you think it does.

Comment: At the end I solve it, making a function and passing through the loop.

@Bugs Sorry it was my first time here and I thought that it was clear if I put at the beginning of the post.

Comment: It's not a problem, here to help. Post an answer @AntonioA and you can mark it as accepted at some point.

Comment: @Bugs do you think is necesary add all the code I did ?  Thank you in advance

Comment: @AntonioA I would say provide as much code necessary for _others_ to understand what you did to fix this problem. Providing too little leaves others guessing or asking for further clarification.